# How to show the checked items in my CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, data-binding, listbox

**EDITED:**

I've created three ListBoxes:

1st ListBox: `listBox`, which shows a list of U.S. States

2nd ListBox: `listBox_Mirror`, which contains a CheckBox to show the selected items of "listBox"

3rd ListBox: `(No Name)`, which is supposed to show the checked items of "listBox_Mirror"

1st ListBox -> 2nd ListBox works fine. However, 2nd ListBox -> 3rd ListBox doesn't work, as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

Procedure:

1. Select all four items in the 1st ListBox.
2. Check the first two items (California and Illioni) in the 2nd ListBox's CheckBox.
3. See if California and Illioni are shown in the 3rd ListBox.

(In my case, nothing is shown.)

Here are my codes:

**StateList.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace CheckedListBox
{
    public class StateList
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Data { get; }
        public StateList()
        {
            Data = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Data.Add("California");
            Data.Add("Illinoi");
            Data.Add("Michigan");
            Data.Add("New York");
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CheckedListBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckedListBox"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="400">
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}" x:Name="listBox" Margin="100,50,100,300" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=listBox}" x:Name="listBox_Mirror" Margin="100,200,100,150">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=listBox_Mirror}" Margin="100,350,100,25"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

    namespace CheckedListBox
    {
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.DataContext = new StateList();
            }
        }
    }
```

... I've changed the Binding property of the 3rd ListBox based on the IntelliSense's suggestion, but it doesn't work, too.
Please tell me how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any mistake with numbers in your description? Otherwise, why do you need third listbox?

Comment: @AlexButenko: I've edited my description. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: I've just found that I could see the `IsChecked` status of `CheckBox` by adding `Checked="ShowState"` to `<CheckBox/>` and adding `private void ShowState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());
        }` to the Code-Behind. Let me see if I can go on further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things, there is no binding to the `IsChecked` and hence nothing ever is set. Also your data is just reference of strings; you should change it to a class with at least two properties, one a Boolean and the other the string you have now. Then bind appropriately.

---

Here is how to do it. I have a model which is defined in code behind but you can get the idea on its structure.

```
  <Page ...
     xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WPFStack.Model"/>
 ...
<Page.Resources>
    <model:Orders x:Key="Orders">
        <model:Order CustomerName="Alpha"
                OrderId="997"
                InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Beta"
                OrderId="998"
                InProgress="False" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Omega"
                OrderId="999"
                InProgress="True" />
        <model:Order CustomerName="Zeta"
                OrderId="1000"
                InProgress="False" />
    </model:Orders>
```

Now with my Listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource Orders}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding CustomerName}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding InProgress, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Running it shows this:

[image]

**Model**

```
namespace WPFStack.Model
{    
    /// <summary>Class Orders which is a placeholder for Xaml example data.</summary>
    public class Orders : List<Order> { }
    public class Order
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public bool InProgress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**Mirror**

Ok, now I will name the controls `lbOriginal` and `lbSelected` to be accessible in the code behind. The new control `lbSelected` will mirror as such without directly connecting to the `lbOriginal` control *or the* data:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbShowSelected">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then I would subscribe to events such as `Loaded`, `Checked` and `UnChecked` on the original.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbOriginal"
         ItemsSource="{StaticResource Orders}"
         Loaded="ProcessChange">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding CustomerName}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding InProgress, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Checked="ProcessChange"
                        Unchecked="ProcessChange"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So then at each step `ProcessChange` method properly updates the mirror (selected as I call it):

```
private void ProcessChange(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lbOriginal.ItemsSource is Orders asOrders)
    {
        lbShowSelected.ItemsSource = null; // Inform control of reset
        lbShowSelected.ItemsSource = asOrders.Where(ord => ord.InProgress)
                                             .Select(ord => ord.CustomerName)
                                             .ToList();
    }
}
```

Then it is in sync and mirroring

[image]

Comment: I might have confused you due to my poor explanation, sorry. Your code works, but it seems like you did my "1st ListBox -> 2nd ListBox" part. Could you possibly do my "2nd ListBox -> 3rd ListBox" part? Really sorry and thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but I got a error "The resource "Orders" could not be resolved." at `ItemsSource="{StaticResource Orders}"`. I added your `Orders` class under the folder `WPFStack_Mirror_ΩmegaMan.Model`. Do I have to add `xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WPFStack_Mirror_ΩmegaMan.Model"` or something? I'm still a beginner, sorry ...

Comment: You need to add the `xmlns:model=` but the namespace has to map to where it is, in your project. Intellisense should list the locations. But you should be able to use your own data....

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you! I simply forgot to add `<Page.Resources>` to my XAML. It was my fault. My bad, sorry.